# Error while run command on terminal

Tags: shimmercat

When I run command "shimmercat devlove" it gives following error:-

[image]

Please find devlove.yaml file:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xhk3lq497zw8y2/devlove.yaml?dl=0

Comment: It looks like a bug. Do you have something running already at port 8000?

Comment: NO, there is nothing running at port 8000

Answer (score 0):

Good question @Atul Rai. I'm not completely sure, but I think it could be related with what is written [here](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/info/articles/structuring-apps/#api-domains). It says:

`...ShimmerCat probes the port to determine if the application is using HTTP/1.1 or FastCGI. The probing operation shows in ShimmerCat's logs, and may also show in the error log of the application.`

Of course if you are not using an `API domain` (you don't have a subkey `port` on your `devlove.yaml` config file) I don't think that `ShimmerCat` has to do these probes, but I can't see another explanation for these error logs. Perhaps it would be useful if you update your question with your `devlove.yaml` file?